# AJAX передача в PHP функцию

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Пытаюсь передать значения из select в PHP функцию при помощи Ajax.

**Файл human.tpl**

```
<form action="/save" method="post" id="human">
 <select name="human[pt][181001]"  style="width:100%" onchange="getdetails(this)">     
 <select name="human[div][181001]" style="width:50%" onchange="getdetails(this)">  
<label class="radio inline">Cюда хочу вставить результат запроса: <?=$staff->PTWorkforceCount($_POST['pt_php1'], $_POST['task_php1'], 181001)?></label>
```

**Файл script.js**

```
function getdetails(){
var pt1 = document.getElementsByName("human[pt][181001]")[0].value;
var task1 = document.getElementsByName("human[div][181001]")[0].value;
var pt2 = document.getElementsByName("human[pt][181002]")[0].value;
var task2 = document.getElementsByName("human[div][181002]")[0].value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/class.php",
    data: {pt_php1:pt1, pt_php2:pt2, task_php1:task1, task_php2:task2}
}).done(function( result )
    {
        //Данные выводятся корректно при каждом изменении одного из select
        alert(" Task1: " +task1 +" PT1: "+pt1+" Task2: " +task2 +" PT2: "+pt2); 
    });
```

}

**Файл сlass.php**

```
class Staff{
 function PTWorkforceCount($pt_id, $task_type, $exam_id)
  {
    $queryCount = 
    "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM `t_wf2pt_ln` 
            JOIN t_pt pt USING (pt_id) 
            WHERE pt.pt_id = UNHEX('".$pt_id."')
            AND wftasktype_id = '".$task_type."'
            AND pt.exam_id = '".$this->sql($exam_id)."'";
    $queryCountN = $this->num($this->fetch($this->query($queryCount)));
    return $queryCountN['c'];
  }
}
```

Файлы расположены следующим образом:

```
*domain/html/js/script.js  
domain/html/human.tpl  
domain/php/class.php*
```

Отрабатывает лишь alert. В label ничего не выводится. В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: В файле `class.php` описывается класс с названием `Staff`. Что вы ожидаете от файла, в котором только описан класс?

Comment: Дополню комментарий выше. В вашем php файле должны быть строки типа `echo (new Staff())->PTWorkforceCount($_POST['pt_php1'], $_POST['task_php1'], 181001);`, например. И уже результат полученный из php вставлять в `label`

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо, Ваш ответ + как раз то, что я искал!